# what does it mean in The Canons of Dort article 17?

Tags: reformed-theology, original-sin

From [What does Calvinism teach about infant death? Do newborn babies go to heaven when they die because they haven't committed sins yet, or do they go to hell because they, like everyone else, have a sinful nature?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Calvinism-teach-about-infant-death-Do-newborn-babies-go-to-heaven-when-they-die-because-they-havent-committed-sins-yet-or-do-they-go-to-hell-because-they-like-everyone-else-have-a-sinful-nature)

> ARTICLE 17
>  Since we are to judge of the will of God from His Word,
> which testifies that **the children of believers are holy**, not by
> nature, but in virtue of the covenant of grace, in which they together
> with the parents are comprehended, godly parents ought not to doubt
> the election and salvation of their children whom it pleases God to
> call out of this life in their infancy

In my interpretation after reading the above quote, it seems that, according to the Calvinist perspective, election/salvation are passed down from generation to generation.

For instance:

- A and B husband and wife, both true believers, have holy children B and C.
- So B and C are true believers.
- B marries D, who is also a true believer because D's parents are true believers.
- C marries E, a true believer due to E's parents also being true believers.
- Children born to B and D are true believers.
- Similarly, children born to C and E are true believers.

This cycle continues, passing down from generation to generation with a formula like this: "If both parents are true believers (holy, the elect) - then their children are also holy, the elect (true believers)."

But that's only my own interpretation. That's why I ask here.

---

[John Calvin, Treatises Against the Anabaptists and Against the Libertines pg. 52](https://wedgewords.wordpress.com/2008/02/24/calvin-on-unrepentant-covenant-children/)

> It is certainly true that when children of believers reach the age of
> discernment [and have never repented or believed] they will have
> alienated themselves from God and destroyed utterly the truth of
> baptism. **But this is not to say that our Lord has not elected them and
> separated them from others in order to grant them His salvation**.

From the above quote, in my own understanding :
A and B husband and wife, both are true believers (the elected). They have a child, name C (also the elected because his parents are the elected).

Time passes by, C reach the age of discernment. C did sinful act. Although C haven't repented yet at that time, but that doesn't mean that God has not elected and separated C from others in order to grant C His salvation.

Comment: B cannot marry if called out of this life in his infancy. Article 17 refers only to children who die in infancy.

Comment: @davidlol, is that mean : only if a child born from true believer parents die before one year old then certainly the child is the elect? Please cmiiw.

Comment: It seems to refer to children whom God has called "out of this life in their infancy" - without stipulating any age. In Bible days the point at which an infant was weaned could be several years old. It was an important developmental stage, unlike today when babies start to be weaned at less than a year old, and nobody thinks anything of it.

Comment: The Canons of Dort were originally written in Latin. The word translated infancy is "infantia" which under Roman law meant the first seven years of life. Essentially, children below the age of reason.